# Uploading images with WebDriver using Selenium-Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So I'm making this python bot to automatized AD posting for 1 reselling site.

And I've hit a wall, the bot logins does everything perfect but when it comes to image upload I can't get it to work.

This is my part that I used for image upload:

```
img_path = '/home/djurovic/Desktop/test/image.png'
imageUploadXpath = '//button[@id="ImageUploadButton"]'
imageUploadElement = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_xpath(imageUploadXpath))
imageUploadElement.send_keys(img_path)
```

The whole script has a lot of code so I don't want go over the top with this question, this is the only part that is bugging me...

This is the site I'm trying to automatized : https://www.kijiji.ca/

This is how image upload section of the website looks like ->

[image]

Here is the html side of the image upload section:

```html
<li class="jsonly">
    <div id="MediaImageUpload" class="clearfix form-section placeholders">
        <p class="images-title">Add at least one photo to complete your ad.</p>
        <div class="images-content">
            <h3>Add photos to attract interest to your ad</h3>
            <div class="images-content-secondary">
                <p>Include pictures with different angles and details. You can upload a maximum of <span id="MaxImages">10</span> photos, that are at least 300px wide or tall (we recommend at least 1000px).</p>
                <p>Drag and drop to change the order of your pictures.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ol id="MediaUploadedImages">
            </ol>

        <span class="field-message" data-for="FileUploadInput"></span>

        <div id="FileInputWrapper" class="file-input-wrapper">
            <input type="hidden" name="file" class="fileErrorBox">

            <div class="imageUploadButtonWrapper">
                <button id="ImageUploadButton" type="button" class="button-update-cancel short file-upload-button">
                    Select Images</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: can you add the html of the button and the input you are sending the path to?

Comment: @MosheSlavin I've edited and added the HTML for the image upload section.

Comment: Thanks, but can you add the actual HTML code? not just the pic... I'm asking this because there is no input tag here...

Comment: Okay, will do that right now...

Comment: @MosheSlavin I've added the html

Comment: Ok, so what changes in the HTML after you manually click the button
?

Comment: It opens the pop up so you can choose the image, in html do not know

Comment: can you try to inspect the popup and add it to the question... this is where you want to add the path to the image...

Comment: Pop up can't be inspected...